# NGINX - stream restart

Tags: nginx

i want to ask something about nginx. I have installed nginx on my VPS server. I can restart it with command : sudo service nginx restart. It restart whole nginx server.

I have more than one stream on nginx (applications). Is posible to restart only one stream not whole nginx?

thanks for answers

Comment: Possibly this? http://serverfault.com/a/378585/317783 (*reloads nginx configs*)

Comment: Hi, thanks. But ... could I reload with this only one stream not whole nginx server?